# How can I get the resource directory in maven to work?

Tags: java, maven, filter, properties, profile

I have a Java Maven web app project that I'm trying to clean up. In the `<build>` section of my `pom.xml`, I have the following:

```
<build>
    <resources>
        <resource>
            <filtering>true</filtering>
            <directory>src/main/resources</directory>
        </resource>
    </resources>
    <filters>
        <filter>profiles/${build.profile.id}.profile.properties</filter>
    </filters>
    [...other properties...]
</build>
```

In my project, which on my Mac is `/Users/anthony/workspace/my-project/`, i `src/main/resources/profiles/`I have `local.profile.properties` and `qa.profile.properties`.

Then, in my maven profiles in my pom, I define `${build.profile.id}` as the following:

```
<profile>
    <id>local</id>
    [...stuff...]
    <properties>
        <build.profile.id>local</build.profile.id> <!-- or qa -->
        [...stuff...]
    </properties>
</properties>
```

When I am in my console and run `$ mvn clean install -Plocal`, I get the following error:

`Failed to execute goal ... on project my-project: Error loading property file '/Users/anthony/workspace/my-project/profiles/local.profile.properties'`.

It seems like Maven is not recognizing the resource directory for my filtering profile properties file. This only works when I explicitly put the entire path of my properties file, like so:

```
<filters>
        <filter>src/main/resources/profiles/${build.profile.id}.profile.properties</filter>
</filters>
```

Is there a way for me to not have to explicitly state `src/main/resources`? I thought that the point of me declaring a resources directory was that I could use it, especially for declaring filtering.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The resource directory only has a meaning as "resources" for the Java artifact being built, but not for Maven itself. For Maven, the "resources" directory has a special meaning in the sense that Maven knows where to copy those files to in the resulting jar-file. But for Maven working with files or filtering files, you have to tell Maven the exact path, as Maven does not know if the filtered file is a resource, a source file, or something else. Also, you could have multiple source or resource directory defined, and Maven would not know, in which one to filter. Thus you always need to specify the full path for Maven.

So, in short:

> Is there a way for me to not have to explicitly state src/main/resources?

No.